# How I can change the style of a down ActionBar?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I'm using ActionBarSherlock, and my app will install on many kinds of smartphones, and for the small smartphones  I divide the actionbar with:

```
android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"
```

My problem appear when the bar is split, because the style only is maintained on the top bar (green), but not on the button bar (gray) :P

Here a screenshot:

[image]

And my current style:

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<!--
    Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
    by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    <!--
        Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
        res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
        backward-compatibility can go here.
    -->
</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/label</item>
    <item name="android:checkboxStyle">@style/checkbox</item>
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/boton</item>
    <item name="android:starStyle">@style/star</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.ActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.ActionBar</item>

    <!-- Agregamos algunos estilos para ver como cambiar los colores de la barra -->
    <item name="android:actionDropDownStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.ActionBar</item>
    <item name="actionDropDownStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.ActionBar</item>
    <item name="actionBarSplitStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.ActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarSplitStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.ActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="label" parent="android:style/Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:padding">4dp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#DF0101</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
</style>

<style name="checkbox" parent="android:style/Widget.CompoundButton.CheckBox">
    <item name="android:textColor">#DF0101</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
</style>

<style name="boton" parent="android:style/Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/btn_form</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
</style>

<style name="star" parent="android:style/Widget.CompoundButton.Star">
    <item name="android:textColor">#DF0101</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.Styled.ActionBar"
       parent="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="background">@drawable/background</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/background</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundStacked">@drawable/background</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundSplit">@drawable/background</item>
    <item name="android:actionButtonStyle">@drawable/background</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

What is the name of this component, in order to add it to the style sheet?

Comment: This is not a "down ActionBar" (or a split Action Bar), you just created an horrible iPhone like tab. The tabs should be placed at the top of the screen if you want to use such pattern.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was I forgot to put this parameter:

```
<item name="backgroundSplit">@drawable/background</item>
```

Only had placed this:

```
<item name="android:backgroundSplit">@drawable/bg_actionbar</item>
```

Sorry :P